# Jumble words Game, alert if correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I was looking into this code of jumble word game, it checks each alphabet if correct & locks it. I basically want to lock it only if the whole word is correct. Can suggest please?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nvw24/

On Stop dragging :

```
stop: function () {
      var textValue = name.split(" ");
         $(".ui-sortable").each(function (sortIndex, sortDiv) {
           $(sortDiv).find("label").each(function (index, elem) {
              if (textValue[sortIndex][index] == $.trim($(elem).text())) {
                 $(elem).removeClass("ls").addClass("correctText");
               } else {
                  $(elem).removeClass("correctText").addClass("ls");
               }
           });
      });

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this snippet to identify the correctness,

```
var total =$(this).find('label');
if(total.length === total.filter('.correctText').length){
    alert('correct');
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3KYxA/2/)

Comment: Woooaahhh...!!! Thanks a tonnn :) Really appreciate your help.. I`ll keep this is mind :)